# Windows Hostname (NetBIOS) in windows 10 kernel driver?

Tags: c, windows-kernel

How can I get the Windows Hostname (NetBIOS)  while coding a windows 10 kernel driver?

I know GetComputerNameExA works in User mode, but how do I do the same in kernel mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get hostname through the following registry path:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName

Read the registry.